# loading sdInteractiveChartPlugin in Symfony action file

Tags: symfony

I want to load sdInteractiveChartPlugin in symfony action but getting error.
Here is my code.

```
$chart = InteractiveChart::newAreaChart();
    $chart->setWidthAndHeight('400', '240');
    $chart->setDataColors(array('#aa0000'));
    $chart->setBaselineColor('#ccc');
    $chart->inlineGraph(array('hits' => array(1,9,5)), array('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday'), 'chart_div');
    $chart->render();
   return sfView::NONE;
```

Comment: $this->getContext()->getConfiguration()->loadHelpers('sdInteractiveChart');

Comment: this is how i am loading it

Comment: but not working i don't know why